# Check if column contains valid values

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a tab delimited file with multiple columns.
I need to check if specific column contains valid values.
e.g. column 13 should only have values 1,2,3,97

```
awk -F"\t" '{ if ($13!=1&&$13!=2&&$13!=3&&$13!=97) print $0}' test-data.txt > check.txt
if [ $( ps -ef | grep check.txt | wc -l ) -gt "1" ];
then
    upload_ok="no"
    echo "failed"
else
    echo "pass"
fi
```

Comment: Why are you running `ps`? You just want to run `grep check.txt | wc -l`

Comment: P.S. Please use SO's `{}` tool to format your code, don't format it as HTML.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ $( ps -ef | grep check.txt | wc -l ) -gt "1" ];
```

should be:

```
if [ $( wc -l < check.txt ) -gt "1" ];
```

Using `ps -ef` makes no sense, that's for checking what processes are running, which has nothing to do with your application. And you don't need `grep`, since you're not searching for anything in the file -- you just want to know how many lines it has, which is what `wc -l` returns.

I'm a little unsure about `-gt 1`. This means that you allow the file to have one invalid line; you only report `failed` if there are at least 2 lines that don't fit the criteria for column 13. If there should actually be no such lines, change to:

```
if [ -s check.txt ];
```

This tests if the file has non-zero length.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what your question is so I've no idea if this answers it or not, but the most robust, extensible way to check for a field ($13) being a member of a set of valid values (1, 2, 3, or 97) in awk is simply to code it the way you'd describe it, e.g.:

```
awk -F'\t' '
BEGIN{ split("1,2,3,97",tmp,/,/); for (i in tmp) valid[tmp[i]] }
!($13 in valid)
' test-data.txt
```

instead of:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ if ($13!=1&&$13!=2&&$13!=3&&$13!=97) print $0}' test-data.txt
```